# How Can customize chartjs doughnut chart border and tooltip

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chart.js, data-visualization

I want to customize chart js doughnut chart as the image below. Using The default border option I can not be able to get my expected result. Is there any way that could help me.

[image: Chart js concept image].

here is my code:

```
var doughnut = document.getElementById("doChart");
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(doughnut, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
    labels:["completed","unpaid", "pending", "canceled"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        data: [4100,2500, 1800, 2300],
        backgroundColor: ['#4c84ff','#29cc97','#8061ef','#fec402'],
        borderColor: ['#4c84ff','#29cc97','#8061ef','#fec402']
     }]
   },
  options: {

  }
});
```

Comment: A similar donut chart is from [Morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/)

Answer (score 1):

The percentage of the chart that is cut out of the middle is defined by cutoutPercentage, e.g.:

```
options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 80, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add     **percentageInnerCutout: 70** in options

options: {
    percentageInnerCutout: 70, // make doughnut chart slim
}